# Acumatica REST endpoint for entity USERS is not updating when using PUT

Tags: acumatica

I extended the defaults web-services endpoint and added SM201010 USERS as an entity with needed fields.

I am able to do a GET and users data is returned perfectly, but when I try to do a PUT to update fields like 'Comment' its returning status code 200 OK success but its not updating the fields.

This is the PUT body example where i tried updating the comment field for the user 'admin':

```
{
    "Login": {"value": "admin"},
    "Comment": {"value": "this is a comment update"}
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: May be you need to trigger Save action too?

Comment: I found out its a bug with CB apis which REST relies on. Fix is in the works by Acumatica.